# Specify notificationID on getNotification() (ParsePushBroadcastReceiver)

Tags: android, parse-platform, push, android-notifications

I'm subclassing ParsePushBroadcastReceiver for my app and overriding getNotification(), everything is working fine but every time I get a push a new notification is created, I would like to pass the same notificationID to the NotificationManager to avoid that.

I've tried to call:

```
NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

mNotificationManager.notify(Constants.NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
```

Before returning my custom Notification on getNotification() but doesn't work. Any ideas how to accomplish that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I solved this same issue.  You will just need to take control of the path that the Notification takes.  Pass in the `Notification` object that comes from `getNotification()` or your own object that you build to your [`NotificationManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager.html) instance to achieve what you want. As long as you use the same value for the id that is passed in as the first parameter it will replace any existing notification with the new one.

```
public class MyParsePushBroadcastReceiver extends ParsePushBroadcastReceiver {

  NotificationManager mNotificationManager;


    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager)context.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        super.onReceive(context, intent);
        ...
   }

   @Override
    protected Notification getNotification(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Notification n = super.getNotification(context, intent);
        int type = intent.getExtras().getInt("NOTIFICATION_TYPE");
        mNotificationManager.notify(type, n);
        return null;
    }
}
```

In the above example I am returning `null` on the `getNotification` and handling the sending to `NotificationManager` myself.  Notice that I am grabbing the `Notification` object from `super.getNotification()` but you are free to build your own `Notification` object using the Notification builder like you are already doing instead.

Keep in mind that you can pull out any data from the Intent bundle that was sent with the push notification so that you can determine what type of notification it is so that you can change your constant values accordingly.  This gives you the ability to target specific rows in the notifications.  In my app I have 3 different types of notifications that might come in and so this way I can only, at most, have 3 different rows occupied by my app in notifications.  If you only have need for 1 notification then you don't need to worry about this and you can continue to use your constant value.